# Starting mongod fork, ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1

Tags: mongodb, unix, amazon-ec2

In attempting to run the command

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log
```

On a amazon ec2 32 bit instance (Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09), I run into the following error:

```
2015-02-18T18:14:09.007+0000 
2015-02-18T18:14:09.007+0000 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling    
enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
2015-02-18T18:14:09.007+0000 
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 17116
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

I also notice no log file is created in the process.

Comment: does `/data/db` exist? errno 1: `#define EPERM            1      /* Operation not permitted */`. That would also explain why no log file is created - the user isn't allowed to.

Comment: It does, I have a number of database files I've been working with in there too.

Comment: `@mnemosyn  ls -al
total 245772
drwxr-xr-x 2 ec2-user root         4096 Feb  5 17:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root         4096 Feb  4 17:40 ..
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 67108864 Feb  5 21:42 brands.0
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 16777216 Feb  5 21:42 brands.ns
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 67108864 Feb  4 22:54 brandsTest2.0
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 16777216 Feb  4 22:54 brandsTest2.ns
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 67108864 Feb 18 17:52 local.0
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 16777216 Feb 18 17:52 local.ns
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user        0 Feb 18 17:59 mongod.lock`

Comment: Hm, then my guess appears to be wrong. I'd still investigate the errno 1 route...

Comment: @mnemosyn where did you find the error codes?  I was looking at [https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md) and couldn't see it.

Comment: These are linux error codes. I googled it, e.g. http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno

Comment: Have you tried running the command without `--fork`? Does it produce an error message? If so, what? If not, what does it say in the log, if it creates one?

Comment: Running mongod works fine on its own.  With the logpath specified I get
`]$ mongod --logpath /var/log/mongod.log
2015-02-19T01:34:12.656+0000 
2015-02-19T01:34:12.656+0000 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
2015-02-19T01:34:12.656+0000 
2015-02-19T01:34:12.657+0000 SEVERE: Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen Failed to open "/var/log/mongod.log"`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I had the same thing and it turned out to be a permissions issue. If the owner of the child process cannot access the log path or the log path does not exist, it will fail.

What I did was put the log directory in my home directory:

```
mkdir ~/log
mongod --fork --logpath ~/log/mongodb.log
```

If you really want to put it in your /var/log directory, just change the permissions.

Comment: For those wondering, I had to change the permissions on */var/log* to 777

Comment: @kabadisha you really shouldn't have 777 on /var/log there's lots of potentially sensitive data stored in that directory. Try changing the directory perms to 740 and create the log file first. Find the user mongod is running as and chown that file. Then chmod the file with 744. I'm just guessing here, but just about any perms are better than 777 on /var/log good luck

Comment: It is a good point. I had to chown the /var/log dir to my user and then give 740 permissions.

Comment: That's fascinating. I was throwing my head to the walls. Thanks!

Comment: How can I do this running mongod from a docker-compose file? @onetwopunch

Comment: @EkaitzHernandezTroyas did you figure out a solution for this? I have a similar problem:

Here's what my Docker-compose looks like:

` rs101:
    image: percona/percona-server-mongodb
    container_name: rs101
    hostname: rs101
    networks:
      - backend
    command: "--port=27017 --replSet rs --auditDestination=file --auditFormat=JSON --auditPath=/var/log/tokumx/audit_101.json"
    volumes:
      - mongo_db_101:/data/db
      - ./mongo-audit-logs/rs101:/var/log/tokumx
    `

Answer (score 12):

I also had the same error, however I used sudo it and ran `sudo mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log`.  As @jryancanty mentioned, it's simply a permissions error.

Comment: I still have the issue, even after using "sudo"

Comment: Using sudo simply changes the error number from 1 to 100 for me.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else running into this error [even if you run it with sudo] make sure that you state the filename of the log file as in: /var/log/mongodb.log. I had just the directory path as in /var/log/ since I miss read the mongo docs.

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue after

```
sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo chown mongod:mongod /var/log/mongodb
```

and all worked.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Simply changing permissions on the directory changed my error message from 1 to 100. I needed to make the mongod user the owner of the directory and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me too as I was having error in spite of setting correct permissions.

Answer (score 3):

I have deleted old

```
/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

and all worked.

Comment: Mine won't run because this file is missing :(. Says `Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a keyfile, it is also possible that the permissions are too open. Make sure you set it to 0400

Answer (score 1):

I incorrectly set the log path to var/mongodb/db/mongo.log instead of /var/mongodb/db/mongo.log so Mongo was trying to access a non-existent folder in /home.

Answer (score 0):

this might work if you see issues with /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock in the log file

sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

Comment: I was trying to intital Sync and in my case the error was : keyFile was owned by root, once I changed it to mongo - it started working -- hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

sudo mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log

In ubuntu no need to change permissions in /var, use full logfile name in logpath

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issues because of user permission , when i logged in ubuntu with user who's don't have permission to create file then also this error was occur.

So , you have to run the command with sudo. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue after remove mongo from EPEL repo (2.x) and install mongo from mongo repo (4.x).

journalctl -xe says:

```
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

In my case I have old log file with root permissions.
Just set correct permission or delete log and check log directory permission.

Answer (score 0):

This error is also generated if you are already having folder for dbpath where db data is being stored and in conf file you gave a new path for dbpath. When you are creating new folders for dbpath, logs and PID then delete the old ones, if they are there.