# ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1,mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I update mongodb from 2.4 to 2.6.
At command line mongodb starts as `mongod`
but as

```
sudo service mongod  start
```

has the error

```
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

What is wrong?I have centos 6.7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591101/starting-mongod-fork-error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-1

Have you checked this question?

Comment: I see log files and there are permision errors.Now I have the error at log file:exception in initAndListen: 10310 Unable to lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock. what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the log settings are correct, you may also want to make sure that you pid file path is not a directory but the full path to a file

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below command to start mongo manually

```
mongod --verbose --fork --logpath ~/mongodb.log
```

Read the log files for errors, it can be some path not available for the home data or log files or a permission issue.