# mongodb service fail after reinstalling it on ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

i was using mongodb and it was fine.

then i wanted to convert it to replica set and i get into some problems and i uninstalled it.

after reinstalling (10 times and doing everything on internet xD) why i check status with `systemctl status` it say failed with exit_code ( i know my conf file dont have problem).
what can i do? i even installed the 3.3 version and even it doesnt start anymore.

i used anything that it came to my mind (purging config files & lot more...).

i really dont want to reinstall my os (really cant).
this is my `sudo systemctl status mongod`

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-02-18 20:05:20 +0330; 8s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 147513 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 147513 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 18 20:05:20 nima-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15AST systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Feb 18 20:05:20 nima-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15AST mongod[147513]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Feb 18 20:05:20 nima-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15AST mongod[147527]: forked process: 147527
Feb 18 20:05:20 nima-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15AST mongod[147513]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 1
Feb 18 20:05:20 nima-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15AST mongod[147513]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
Feb 18 20:05:20 nima-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15AST systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 18 20:05:20 nima-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15AST systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting mongod fork, ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591101/starting-mongod-fork-error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-1)

Comment: @AliTou im installing it again and if the error exists i will send it to you (but i should state that when i install mongodb from tarball it works fine but again not from apt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the default `mongodb` port from `port 27017` to `port 27018` in `/etc/mongod.conf`.

I'm sure this will come handy to a lot of people.

And for the last part, after uninstalling `mongodb` I removed `mongod.service` files (every file) in the `system` and `systemd` directories in root and installed `mongodb` again.
(so I think uninstalling `mongodb` wasn't complete at first time. And 2 instances interfere with each other. Now everything works fine in `mongodb` with `port 27018`).